# The read failed: PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I do not want to use the admin functionality or turn down read/write rules to true always.

Errors that are getting in read are
  The read failed: PERMISSION_DENIED

But I could see the data is getting retrieved.

For insert with set
   FIREBASE WARNING: set at /***/profile failed: permission_denied

But insert is getting failed.

Could some one please suggest is this is a normal behaviour and how to authenticate as a normal user and do just insert/updates.I do not want to use any admin functionalities like creating new documents.

I have two firebase end points so the issue currently exist for the secondary one.
firebase.initializeApp(config,'message');

Below method is showing read failed in console while page loads,but I could see the alerts if I am calling this method using a user click along with the error.Tried the same with .on('child_added'  as well,but not getting called.

```
this.firebaseVideoNodeRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        alert("data" + JSON.stringify(snapshot));
        }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("My read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
```

//Below code also failing with 
2.chunk.js:11107 Uncaught (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: 
    Permission denied

```
this.firebaseVideoNodeRef.set(anyJSONsample);
```

My security rules are the default one in new firebase console.

Thanks,
Sarath.

Comment: Hi Sarath,
How are you authenticating users right now? Can you please update your answer to include the code where the issue occurs? Thanks!

Comment: As Jen said, it would help if you could show us: Your security rules in question, and how you try to read and write. Please see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks Jen/Chris, added more details.

Comment: Also one more behaviour noticed is  
   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
     alert(user);//This user is coming as null.
   });   I believe firebase.launchApp(credentialsJson) is only needed as rules is default with checks for auth!=null not for any user.  Or does it require an auth with email/anonymous call back.Another strange behaviour is my primary firebase end point is returning data with out any changes.

Comment: This has been fixed after adding a server side call to create user from uid and do the inserts/updates from the onAuthStateChanged callback after signing with custom token.